# Using unnamed namespace to redefine friend class in an API and access private members?

Tags: c++, friend

I'm trying to access some private members of a class that's part of an API that I do not have the ability to change.

Listing 1: **api.h**

```
namespace api {
    class Bar;

    class Foo {
    public:
        const int& getSecret() const { return secretValue; }
    private:
        int secretValue;
        friend class Bar;
    };
}
```

Listing 2: **program.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "api.h"

namespace {
    class api::Bar {
        public:
            void touchFooSecretly(api::Foo& f) { f.secretValue = 42; }
    };
}

int main() 
{
    api::Foo f;
    api::Bar b;

    b.touchFooSecretly(f);

    std::cout << f.getSecret() << std::endl; // 42 (Solaris)
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles (and runs) fine in Oracle Solaris Studio 12.3, but clang and g++ (understandably) have a problem with it:

```
program.cpp:5:13: error: cannot define or redeclare 'Bar' here because namespace '' does not enclose namespace 'api'
```

This hack is currently being employed for the sake of efficiency, with good knowledge of how the class operates internally.  Is there a way to achieve a similar trick in clang such that I can change the meaning of a friend class for my translation unit alone?

Or, failing that, any trick that lets me access a private member in a class where I cannot modify the declarations would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want to have multiple different definitions of `Bar` throughout the program? If so, even if you succeed to compile it, the behaviour will be undefined.

Comment: My translation unit will have my definition of Bar and the rest of the application will remain unaffected (as it has already been compiled and linked).  I think that's well-defined but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Another hack is to add `#define private public` before `#include "api.h"` and `#undef private` after. It's awful, but then secretValue will become public...and this will most likely compile with any compiler ;-)

Comment: @jpo38 That's brilliant, never thought to do something so crazy.  Thanks for trying to answer the question - feel free to post as an answer and I can accept it if it really is the only work-around.

Comment: @Dragos You are welcome, good to know it helps. However, I cannot post this as an answer because it does not answer your original question (and too many downvoters are waiting for me to do it...;-). Please add to your question something like "Any other solution helping me to access secretValue private attribute is acceptable", and then I can post my answer ;-)

Comment: @jpo38 Yes, I was rather looking forward to downvoting your answer for trying to help :P ... anyway, edit done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented in the question's post, I don't know how to fix this namespace problem. But, as requested by the author, `any trick that lets me access a private member in a class where I cannot modify the declarations would be appreciated!`...here is my trick:

```
#define private public
#include "api.h"
#undef private
```

That's awful, but if you know what you are doing, this will make all private members declared in classes of "api.h" (+ all others classes possibly declared in files includes by "api.h") be public!